# Erlang based chat (load balancing and notifications distribution)

Tags: erlang

We are going to develop a backend for our messenger, so I have one idea which I want describe here, maybe someone can give me an advice.

1) Idea:

Nginx - redirects request to random node (round robin) ->
Erlang cluster - redirects to actual node (we choose node with minimum number of processes) ->
Handshake ->
Upgrade to WebSocket.

Every node in cluster has ETS table that contains number of processes for every node (fields - node, num_processes). Every node, every 5 secs sends its number of processes to all the nodes in a cluster.

So we don't need to have a master node, because every node can do load balancing.

2) Additional question:

Is it a good idea to register user's active WebSocket connections (pids) globally with gproc? We need this list for every user to send notifications through ws to enduser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yep - this is a good scheme. An improvement you can make is to increment the load of a remote node every time you balance load to another node. This is like keeping an estimate for remote node load and stops you from sending all load to one node for five seconds at a time. Every time you receive a broadcast from another node, just overwrite your local estimate - this will fix up any missing updates and ensure your estimates stay within a small amount of the actual remote value.

2) You could use a gproc named property `{Username, true}` for each websocket process - this will let you find all websocket sessions for a user throughout the cluster.

I forget what underlying protocol gproc uses for global registrations and what cost you'll have for registering/deregistering properties all the time throughout the cluster. I worked on a very similar system (user presence and messaging with sessions and multi-node load balancing) a while back and ended up writing [ngproc](https://github.com/ngmoco/ngproc) in order to support cheap name lookup with conflict resolution after partitions. It's available as open source and might provide some ideas you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting:

- What kind of amount of users are you designing for?
- How much data will there be sent on the chat? Is it for text, images, or video?
- What are you load-balancing for, i.e. which resource do you expect to be the  critical one?
- What do you expect to happen if a node dies?

Comment: 1) More than 1 million users (more than 200 thousand online)
2) We will send only text messages with metadata (images, video and audio will be stored on the cluster of "media" servers)
3) I'm trying to spread all the user's WebSocket connections among the cluster
4) When node dies, all user's clients will try to reconnect, cause ping fails (WebSocket connections of died node will be spread among alive nodes)